# Array Initialization

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, initialization, nsmutablearray

The following code for initialization of array works ::

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Toy Story 3",@"Inception",nil];
 self.list = [array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    [array release];
 [super viewDidLoad];
```

But the following code doesnt. The iPhone Simulator Terminates as soon as I try to scroll the Table View which i used to view the array. (Only after i scroll onto empty tableViewCells)

```
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
 NSString *plistPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"MovieList" ofType:@"plist"];
 NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
 NSLog([array objectAtIndex:1]);
 self.list = [array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    [array release];
 [super viewDidLoad];
```

This was an example app from the Book "Beginning iPhone Development" by Dave Mark. In the example , they have initialized the array within the code, while i have tried to initialize it from a external file.

The console Log ::

```
2010-12-22 20:57:43.772 Nav[2474:40b] WARNING: Using legacy cell layout due to delegate implementation of tableView:accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath: in <RootViewController: 0x9908870>.  Please remove your implementation of this method and set the cell properties accessoryType and/or editingAccessoryType to move to the new cell layout behavior.  This method will no longer be called in a future release.
2010-12-22 20:58:12.480 Nav[2474:40b] WARNING: Using legacy cell layout due to delegate implementation of tableView:accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath: in <DisclosureButtonController: 0x9b32ab0>.  Please remove your implementation of this method and set the cell properties accessoryType and/or editingAccessoryType to move to the new cell layout behavior.  This method will no longer be called in a future release.
2010-12-22 20:59:13.299 Nav[2474:40b] -[UIDeviceRGBColor length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9b3d900
2010-12-22 20:59:13.301 Nav[2474:40b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIDeviceRGBColor length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9b3d900'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00db2be9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f075c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00db46fb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00d24366 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00d23f22 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   UIKit                               0x0051a9ca -[UITableViewCellLayoutManager layoutSubviewsOfCell:] + 3424
    6   UIKit                               0x00482e02 -[UITableViewCell layoutSubviews] + 95
    7   QuartzCore                          0x01c70451 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 181
    8   QuartzCore                          0x01c7017c CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 220
    9   QuartzCore                          0x01c6937c _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 310
    10  QuartzCore                          0x01c690d0 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 292
    11  QuartzCore                          0x01c997d5 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 99
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00d93fbb __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 27
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00d290e7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 295
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00cf1bd7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1575
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00cf1240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00cf1161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    17  GraphicsServices                    0x016e7268 GSEventRunModal + 217
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x016e732d GSEventRun + 115
    19  UIKit                               0x002ca42e UIApplicationMain + 1160
    20  Nav                                 0x00002598 main + 102
    21  Nav                                 0x00002529 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

enter code here
```

Comment: Post the line on which the app crashes as well as any messages that appear in your log.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like this is a perfect job for the debugger, doesn't it? Why not set a breakpoint on the first line and make sure nothing is unexpectedly nil or out of bounds as you step through and inspect your variables? Perhaps paying attention to the error that's undoubtedly logged to the console might be helpful, too?

Given you've mentioned neither the line on which it terminates nor any log messages, this is about as specific as anyone can get.

Comment: Okay ... so which line fails? What are the results of your using the debugger to step through the code? We don't have crystal balls and we're not being paid to hold your hand: *help us help you*.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to NSLog needs to be an NSString. The object you're passing to it appears to be part of the UIColor cluster. I suggest you change to:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [array objectAtIndex:1]);
```

So the first argument is definitely a string and it says just to print a description of whichever object is the next argument.